# ffmpeg skips first 5 secs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to copy the first minute of an mp4 file, but getting a strange result in which I try to play the file output from ffmpeg and the first 5 secs are missing!

I have tried using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i The\ Big\ Fight\ \(1972\).mp4 -ss 0 -t 30 -c copy fight.mp4
```

as well as this command:

```
ffmpeg -i The\ Big\ Fight\ \(1972\).mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -ss 0 -t 00:0:30 fight.mp4
```

both result in the video starting to play at 05s, and nothing exisiting prior to that 05s

Answer (score 0):

this command seems to work:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i The\ Big\ Fight\ \(1972\).mp4 -to 45 -c:v copy -c:a copy newfight.mp4
```